# Adding 3rd Party Code to my Android Studio Project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm having issues when I try to use [Bindroid](https://github.com/depoll/bindroid) in my Android Studio Project. I've set up a boilerplate app to create a HelloWorld example using Bindroid. I cloned the Bindroid source into my /libs folder. But when I go to run my app, I get a `package Bindroid does not exist` error.

I need to know how to import this code and use it with my project. For example, where should I place this code? How do I configure my project to use it? Here's my project structure:

[image]

**EDIT**

So I've added Bindroid according to the instructions, here is the resulting structure:
[image]

And here is my apps `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sg.spencergardner.finance5"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile project(':Bindroid:Bindroid')
}
```

And my project's settings.gradle:

```
include ':app'
include ":Bindroid"
```

Comment: What is the folder structure of your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy all the contents of this https://github.com/depoll/bindroid/tree/master/Bindroid under the folder name "Bindroid".

In your app's build.gradle, add.

```
     compile project(':Bindroid:Bindroid')
```

:Bindroid:Bindroid corresponds to "Project Folder":"App/Library Folder". See https://github.com/depoll/bindroid/blob/master/BindroidSample/build.gradle#L5.

Also in your settings.gradle, you need to add ":app" and ":Bindroid".

Comment: Okay, I've added like I think you mean, and I've changed the post to reflect your suggestions, and I get a Error:(25, 0) Project with path ':Bindroid:Bindroid' could not be found in project ':app'. in my build.grade

Comment: I believe your Project is Finance5 so use compile project(':Finance5:Bindroid') instead.

Comment: I placed the Bindroid code under Finance5/app/libs not "Library" like you mentioned. I assumed libs was correct. Still getting the same error that Project with Path ':Finance5:Bindroid' could not be fund in project ':app'

Comment: Bindroid should not be inside app. It should be in the same level as the app folder.

Comment: Just follow the Github repo. The BindroidSample is basically your app.